# Excel crashes when attempting to grab value from Userform ComboBox

Tags: excel, vba

A file that has worked fine for months has suddenly started to crash (file goes into "not responding" and completely closes) when running a long script that creates PDF files. I was able to step-through and found out that the culprit for the recurrent crashing was this line here:

```
syear = ufStartAssessment.cbYear.Value
```

Where `syear` is a Long, `ufStartAssessment` is a UserForm and `cbYear` is a ComboBox on that UserForm. The UserForm has not been unloaded when it reaches this step, and the ComboBox definitely has a value. Is the UserForm/ComboBox just corrupted? Is my only solution to recreate them?

EDIT: I tried to export and re-import the UserForm and got:

[image: img1]

And checking the log file that was generated, the error is:

> Line 8: Property OleObjectBlob in ufStartAssessment had an invalid file reference.

EDIT2:

I should add that when I comment this line out and replace it with `syear = 2020`, it works fine. So the issue must be with the UserForm.

Comment: What are you using to generate PDFs?  Presumably a plug-in? Is it possible that your plug-ins got uninstalled or misconfigured? Also, is it possible that the file already exists or is in a read-only directory or path doesn't exist, such that your file reference is "invalid" for one of those reasons?

Comment: @Marc I'm just using `ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF` to create them, but I know that's not the issue because when I comment out my `syear` line and replace it with `syear = 2020` it works fine. So the issue has to be with the UserForm and grabbing the value from it.

Comment: Add a BreakPoint at `syear = ufStartAssessment.cbYear.Value`. Run your to so it pause just before executing that line. Does the `ufStartAssessment.cbYear.Value` contains a character that cannot be converted into a number? Try in Immediate Window: `?CLng(ufStartAssessment.cbYear.Value),ufStartAssessment.cbYear.Value` and see what returns.

Comment: Is your script running entirely inside the userform? Or does it call subs / functions from standard modules and is the reference to the userforms combobox in one of those? Or does it run from a standard module where it opens the userform (modal or modeless)?

Comment: Do you have missing references? (VBE Tools > references), Maybe deleting of the ComboBox and adding a new one with another name (also code) will help.

Comment: I'm referring to @PatricK Comment. Maybe add right before the Line: Debug:Print ufStartAssessment.cbYear.Value and check wheter it behaves as expected

Comment: @PatricK No invalid characters, the only options are 2018, 2019 and 2020 and I've used them all before in testing.

Comment: @horst The script starts from the UserForm but then calls subs in other modules, then refers back to the UserForm

Comment: @EvR No missing references. Ultimately, recreating this UserForm exactly fixed the problem, it's just a drag...

Comment: Can you try create a new ComboBox same as cbYear, then delete original cbYear, and rename the new one as cbYear, will that work? Is it only you can edit the macro?

Comment: If you have a copy of the old exported userform then may i have it?

Comment: @PatricK I chose to just remake the userform entirely, that fixed the issue. Maybe I should've started with the combobox...

Comment: @SiddharthRout I have it exported as a FRM file, does that work? How can I get it to you?

Comment: There are two files `.Frm.` and `.Frx`. Zip them up and upload it in say www.wikisend.com or dropbox or any free file sharing site. Then sahre the link here

Comment: @SiddharthRout http://wikisend.com/download/917576/ufStartAssessment.frx http://wikisend.com/download/852232/ufStartAssessment2.frm I think these are them... thanks for taking a look.

Comment: I was able to import the files without any issues

Answer (score -2):

I am afraid you will have to try create it new, I experience the same issue from time to time with my Workooks and it was that the whole File did gone corrupt without any reason.

recreating the File solved it for me.